# Site is not accessible publicly despite it is running in docker-compose

Tags: docker, .net-core, amazon-ec2

I have created the Ubuntu EC2 Instances with the default VPC setting.

I was able to run the docker-compose on the Linux (Ubuntu) ec2 instances.

```
ubuntu@ip-XXX-XX-XX-XXX:~/someapp-Docoker$ sudo docker compose up
WARN[0000] The "APPDATA" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "APPDATA" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
[+] Running 2/2
 ✔ Network docoker_default              Created                                                                                                                               0.1s
 ✔ Container docoker-webapplication2-1  Created                                                                                                                               0.2s
Attaching to docoker-webapplication2-1
docoker-webapplication2-1  | warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.FileSystemXmlRepository[60]
docoker-webapplication2-1  |       Storing keys in a directory '/root/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' that may not be persisted outside of the container. Protected data will be unavailable when container is destroyed.
docoker-webapplication2-1  | warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35]
docoker-webapplication2-1  |       No XML encryptor configured. Key {fc20c818-5f4c-470e-a39b-ab3b65a78b29} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.
docoker-webapplication2-1  | info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
docoker-webapplication2-1  |       Now listening on: https://[::]:443
docoker-webapplication2-1  | info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
docoker-webapplication2-1  |       Now listening on: http://[::]:80
docoker-webapplication2-1  | info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
docoker-webapplication2-1  |       Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
docoker-webapplication2-1  | info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
docoker-webapplication2-1  |       Hosting environment: Development
docoker-webapplication2-1  | info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
docoker-webapplication2-1  |       Content root path: /app
```

But I am not able to access the application publicly.

I have the following configuration in docker-compose files

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  webapplication2:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}webapplication2
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: WebApplication2/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
      - "8001:443"
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+;http://+
      - ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=8001
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=<Cert Pass>
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/aspnetapp.pfx
    volumes:
      - /home/ubuntu/.aspnet/https:/https/
```

in my inbound rules of the ec2 instance, I have setup the following port,

[image]

But still not able to access the site.

What I am missing in this configuration?

Comment: do your instance have a public IP assigned, and is it in a public subnet (with an Internet Gateway attached to it)?

Comment: @FilippoTestini Yes!!

Answer (score 0):

The environment should be like this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/docker-compose-https?view=aspnetcore-7.0

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  webapplication2:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}webapplication2
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: WebApplication2/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
      - "8001:443"
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=<Cert Pass>
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/aspnetapp.pfx
    volumes:
      - /home/ubuntu/.aspnet/https:/https/
```